# Java - Using Constructors for the first time - Homework

Tags: java, constructor

In my program, it is supposed to read in the Student Name, ID Number, and GPA, assign it to whichever student is specified, and print it out. Everything compiles fine but it gives the error `Error: Could not find or load main class Lab10.java`. Any help is appreciated :).

Here are my programs:

```
public class Lab10
{ 
    private final static String NAME = "Glenn Coffey III";
    private final static int STUID = 123456789;
    private final static double GPA1 = 4.00;
    private final static double GPA2 = 2.34;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student stu1;
        stu1 = new Student(NAME, STUID, GPA1);
        System.out.println("\nName: " + stu1.getName());
        System.out.println("Id Number: " + stu1.getIdNum());
        System.out.println("GPA: " + stu1.getGPA());
        stu1.setGPA(GPA2);
        System.out.println(stu1 + "\n");

        Student stu2;
        stu2 = new Student("Pistol Pete", 000000001, 4.00);
        System.out.println("\nName: " + stu2.getName());
        System.out.println("Id Number: " + stu2.getIdNum());
        System.out.println("GPA: " + stu2.getGPA());
        System.out.println(stu2 + "\n");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Student
{
    private String name;
    private int idNum;
    private double gpa;
    public Student(String namePar, int idNumPar, double gpaPar)
    {
        name = namePar;
        idNum = idNumPar;
        gpa = gpaPar;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public double getGPA()
    {
        return gpa;
    }
    public int getIdNum()
    {
        return idNum;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    public void setGPA(double d)
    {
        gpa = d;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = String.format("Name: %s, \nId Number: %d, \nGPA: %f, \nStudent name: %s, "
                + "\nStudent ID num: %d, \nStudent GPA: %f,", name, idNum, gpa, name, idNum, gpa);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact terminal command did you issue to get that error?

Comment: If you tried to run it by typing `java Lab10.java`, don't.  Try `java Lab10`.  (That's how it works on the Windows system I'm using.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have issued the wrong terminal command. Try the following:

```
javac Lab10.java
java Lab10
```